# Suddenly computer no longer boots from USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot

I was running Tails from a USB flash drive until I shut it down one day and it stopped booting. Afterwards, I booted into Windows to fix it, and the system didn't even seemed to recognize it. So I opened my partition manager to check on it, and everything looked normal. And it wasn't formatted in ext3 or anything, so it should've showed up in Explorer.

So far, I have tried using LiLi USB Creator and UNetBootIn; formatting into FAT32, NTFS, and FAT16; deleting all partitions; and initializing to GPT.

I have tested with another live OS (Tinycore) on my main computer and another one with similar results.

When I try to boot from the drive, I select it from the BIOS boot menu after pressing F12.

What happens after telling it to boot is I get a screen with white text on black, and it says "Intel UNDI ... For Realtek ... PCI-E Ethernet Controller ... PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable / PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM...." and it repeats the message infinitely. It looks like it's trying to boot over LAN instead of USB.

Comment: Make sure the boot order hasn't changed in the BIOS... Are those boot messages from your BIOS or whatever OS was on the USB key?  If it's the prior (BIOS), why is network booting enabled if you don't use it?  Also, it's possible the USB key is corrupted (they do have a finite lifespan with respect to the number of times a sector can be written to).

Comment: Anthony, please **register** your account, and then use the process here to merge your accounts: http://superuser.com/help/user-merge – seems you've lost your cookie and your question & answer need to be reassociated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it stopped working in the first place, but it turns out that all I needed to do was write a live CD and then use the Tails USB Installer.